# Solving equation that involves nepper number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have the following equation.

$$\frac{1}{5} = \large e^{\frac{10^{-4}}{x}}$$

I assume that x will be $0.0621$ but I can't remember how does one solves such equation. I recall that it involves using logarithm or LN... can you please help me remember?

Comment: "nepper"=Napier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the logarithm with base $e$ on both sides, and use the property $\log_a a^x=x$, then:

$$\ln 1/5 = 10^{-4}/x$$
$$x=\frac{10^{-4}}{\ln\frac{1}{5}} $$

Answer (score 2):

You can take the logarithm on both side and get

$$\ln\frac{1}{5}=\frac{10^{-4}}{x}$$

so that

$$ x = \frac{10^{-4}}{-\ln 5}=-6.21\times 10^{-5}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\ln\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)=-\ln(5)&=\ln\left(e^{10^{-4}}/x\right)\\
&\Rightarrow -\ln(5)=10^{-4}/x\\
&\Rightarrow x=\frac{10^{-4}}{-\ln(5)}
\end{align}$$